# Smooth Structures as equivalence classes of smooth atlases

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

I have an issue regarding an exercise that deals with smooth structures as equivalence classes of smooth atlases.

[image]

Atlases are said to be compatible if any two of their charts are.

I was able to show a) but I am a bit confused by b). My understanding is that if $\mathcal{S}_U, \mathcal{S}_V$ are compatible on $U \cap V$ this means that for representatives $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathcal{S}_U$ and $\mathcal{V}$ of $\mathcal{S}_V$ the charts in the sets

$$
\{ \varphi: W \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{U} \, \mid \, W \subseteq U \cap V\} 
$$

$$
\{ \psi: W \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{V} \, \mid \, W \subseteq U \cap V \}
$$

are compatible (that is, for each two charts the associated coordinate change maps are $C^{\infty}$).

In order to solve this exercise I have to show that there is a unique smooth structure $\mathcal{S}$ such that every representative $C$ of $\mathcal{S}$ is a smooth atlas on $\mathcal{M}$. Moreover,the charts in the set

$$
\{ \delta: W \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{C} \, \mid \, W \subseteq U \} 
$$

must compatible with the charts in the set

$$
\{ \varphi: W \to \mathbb{R}^k  \in \mathcal{U} \, \mid \, W \subseteq U \}
$$

which is associated with a representative $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathcal{S}_U$. Similarly, the charts in the set

$$
\{ \delta: W \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{C} \, \mid \, W \subseteq V \} 
$$

must be compatible with charts in the set

$$
\{ \psi: W \to \mathbb{R}^k  \in \mathcal{V} \, \mid \, W \subseteq V \}
$$

which is associated with a representative $\mathcal{V}$ of $\mathcal{S}_V$.

My idea was to show that the union of representatives of $\mathcal{S}_U$ and $\mathcal{S}_V$ form smooth atlases on $M$ and then take $\mathcal{S}$ to be the equivalence class containing these atlases. Consider the charts

$$
\varphi: W \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{U}  \ , W \subseteq U \\
\psi: \tilde{W} \to \mathbb{R}^k \in \mathcal{V} \ ,  \tilde{W} \subseteq  V\
$$

and their restrictions

$$
\varphi: W \cap \tilde{W} \to \mathbb{R}^k \ , W \cap \tilde{W} \subseteq U \cap V\ \\
\psi: W \cap \tilde{W} \to \mathbb{R}^k \ , W \cap \tilde{W} \subseteq U \cap V\
$$

Because $W \cap \tilde{W} \subseteq U \cap V\ $ we can use the assumption from above to conclude that $\varphi, \psi$ are compatible on $U \cap V$. This means that the associated coordinate change map and its inverse

$$
f: \varphi(W \cap \tilde{W}) \to \psi(W \cap \tilde{W}) \\
f^{-1}: \psi(W \cap \tilde{W}) \to \varphi(W \cap \tilde{W}) 
$$

are both $C^{\infty}$. But then $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V}$ are compatible and it follows that $\mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V}$ is a smooth atlas of $M$ (the latter is true since $U \cup V=M$). Now we must show that atlases of the form $\mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V}$ are compatible. This is true because for two atlases $\mathcal{U}_1 \cup \mathcal{V}_1$, $\mathcal{U}_2 \cup \mathcal{V}_2$  where $U_1,U_2 \in \mathcal{S}_U$ and $V_1,V_2 \in \mathcal{S}_V$ any of their charts are compatible (if the charts come from representatives of the same equivalence class (say from $U_1$ and $U_2$) they are compatible by definition, if they come from representatives of distinct equivalence classes (say from $U_1$ and $V_2$) they can be shown to be compatible with the arguments from before). Thus $\mathcal{S}$ is an equivalence class.

In particular, on subsets $W \subseteq U$ the charts of representatives from $\mathcal{S}_U$ are compatible with the charts of representatives from $\mathcal{S}$. This is true because the representatives of $\mathcal{S}$ contain representatives of $\mathcal{S}_U$ and of course two representatives from the same equivalence class are compatible. The same argument also holds for $\mathcal{S}_V$.

However I still have doubts that my reasoning is correct. Is there a flaw in my solution?